# Hide SSID from the list of available wifi networks in macOS?

Tags: macos, wifi, command-line, airport, 802.1x

Is there any way to hide particular SSID names from the list of available networks?

Below command gives list of wifi networks,

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -s`

how can I hide particular SSID from the above list?

Below command is only removing from preferred networks list

```
networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork en0 AC_BYOD
```

I don't even want see the same on the wifi window on the MacBook status bar.

is it possible to filter SSIDs on OSX?

Comment: Do you really want the SSID to be invisible on your computer? Otherwise you could disable SSID broadcasting in your modem or router settings. In this case, the SSID will be invisible to anyone.

Comment: Hi @DaktaMoriamé ,Thanks for your comment, i want particular SSID to invisible only on my computer. Is it possible to filter SSIDs on my OSX machine? its possible on windows.